# Log not readable after rotation by daemontools

Tags: centos, logging, logrotate, daemontools, log-rotation

I have a log, which looks perfectly fine.  However, after the log rotation by daemontools, it is no longer human readable.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could be compressed by logrotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My spidey-sense tingles and tells me you are trying to comb through a rotated log file with `more` or `cat`. Better to use `zless`, `zcat`, `zgrep` or similar. Or, if the daemontools does compress the files with `bzip`, then `bzless`, `bzcat`, `bzgrep` ...

If in doubt, you can do `file /path/to/rotated/log` and check out the output.